# How can I determine if SQL Server Management Studio Express (2005) is installed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, installation

I need a way to determine from Wise Install Script if SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 is installed on computer.  Does someone know a Registry entry or something that will be present when SSMSE is installed?

Answer (score 1):

Most reliable way to detect it would be to use the MSI database to detect the state of SQL Server Management Studio.

There is a COM object you can use to query the MSI database:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369432.aspx

the Installer.Products property can tell you what products/packages are installed.  Installer.ProductState can tell you the state of the product/package.

Most installer systems can also do the same checks - either use the API, Orca or similar MSI tool to find the product SQL Mgmt Studio Package/Product ID.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion
```

Get the value of CurrentVersion key and compare it with the version of SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this - this key can also indicate that only the service is installed.